# Blank Images after Full Site Restoration with Akeeba

Tags: akeebabackup

I try to run a copy of a Joomla website locally using Xampp. I followed
the restoration workflow in [this](https://www.akeeba.com/videos/1212-akeeba-backup/1618-abtc04-restore-site-new-server.html) tutorial. Everything works fine except that some images are missing on the page. Interestingly this only happens on Windows machines. On Linux, everything works fine. Anyone with a similar experience?

Comment: I’m just guessing but usually I’ve seen this happening because of the forward slash (/) (or lack of it) at the beginning of the images’ links on your Joomla site. Different systems and servers handles that differently. The problem can be handled by settings of the servers...

Comment: Thanks for your reply - can you be more specific about the settings you mentioned? I experimented with the RewriteBase setting in the .htaccess file but nothing helped.

Comment: I agree when some environments load a file and other environments don't, it often points to the path syntax -- more specifically the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.  Please investigate this possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have time at the moment to go into this subject more, I just wanted to point you to a direction on handling this issue. You should study similar articles like this one here: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/relative-double-slashes-url.html

Comment: @benno please take our [tour].  If you manage to self-solve your issue, please post an educational answer and mark it with the green tick so that this page is deemed resolved.  If you cannot self-solve, but find more relevant clues, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. It was related to my PHP installation.
In order for my site to work correctly, the gd extension had to be loaded in the php.ini file. The file is located in the directory C:\xampp\php.
Just uncomment the following line

```
extension=gd
```